# Cartoon about a group of teenagers whose souls travel to multiple worlds with monsters

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I remember very little but enough... I know that there were 3 worlds, a real one, a mid-world kind of with a teleporter, and the world with all the creatures. The first episode was in the desert and there was a good monster that saved the main guys from a bad one. Before he saved them he said every end is a beginning and every beginning is an end.

Please help me; I've tried everything. I saw it on [Orlando Kids](http://www.orlando-kids.tv/), I think it was not Japanese. I live in Croatia, so I saw it there. It was aimed at kids, but not younger kids. The main characters were human, around 15 years old. The teleporter was in the middle of a big structure. It was a 6 piece tp, so every circle was one, and it was shaped like a star. There were robots working there; they carried food and other things.

I remember that all the creatures thought that the humans are evil, all but the one, the "lord" of all of them. And yes, the main character got to the world by some sort of a device that he found and it belonged to another kid who lost it and they were able to transform in the creatures from the world by it. When they are in the "other world", their body stays in the real world and acts normally but their soul gets transported to the mid-world

Comment: Do you know roughly when it was on air?

Comment: Some prompts for extra clues you might be able to [edit] in: When did you see it? In what country? Do you know where it was made (e.g. was it tanslated from Japanese)? What kind of age range was it aimed at? Do you remember any other details about what the teleporter looked like, what kind of creatures and monsters? Were the main characters human? Children or adults?

Comment: **You might also want to use a more descriptive question title**

Comment: Please add more details; as the questions stands, it's too vague. Welcome to the SF & Fantasy stack, by the way.

Comment: See also these pages for some tips: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: I remember that all the creatures thought that the humans are evil... all but the one, the "lord" of all of them... and yes, the main character got to the world by some sort of a device that he found and it belonged to another kid who lost it. and when they are in the "other world" their body stays in the real world and acted normaly but their soul got transported in the mid-world

Comment: @MateoKasunić: Please check my answer and see if it's what you're looking for. If so, please vote up and click on the check mark to accept it.

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141953/23243, but that one has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I believe you're looking for *[Chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series))*.

> Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.
>
> There are two parts to the Chaotic world, Chaotic itself and Perim. Chaotic is where the people play an advanced version of the card/online game where they transform into the creatures. The games can be watched via monitor by other players.
>
> The second part is Perim. In Perim the creatures, locations and items from the game are real. Players from the Chaotic game can teleport into Perim and scan the locations, creatures and items with their scanners, gaining the ability to use them in their game. There are four tribes in Perim. Two tribes, the Overworld and the Underworld, have been at war over a great power called the Cothica. Despite their names, there is no definite Good and evil tribe, as both have different stories and interpretations of how the war began, with each tribe seeing the other as being evil. The Danians and Mipedians have since joined the war, turning it into a four-way conflict over the Cothica. It is said that the Mipedians were once united with the Overworlders and the Danians united with the Underworlders. It is still unknown why they separated

It is [one of the features](http://www.orlando-kids.tv/shows/Chaotic/) on Orlando Kids. It has two other worlds, which are accessible by a device that the main character acquires from his friend (well, he already had the device, but got the code from Kaz). They are teenagers. Chaotic has a teleporter to Perim. There are robots on the Chaotic.

And, indeed, their bodies stay on Earth:

> When the players are in Chaotic/Perim they exist simultaneously on Earth. When a Chaotic player leaves Chaotic they become one person again and the Earth version of the player gains the memories of anything they experienced in the Chaotic/Perim world. This is awkward the first time they transport, as their online deck is blocked so that their Chaotic self can use it and their scanner becomes non functional, causing many people to believe they have broken their scanners until they are re-united with their Chaotic self.

### Intro

Comment: OMG... Thank you so much... I don't know what to tell you

Comment: ^_^ Clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons will be thanks enough.