# Anime/Show in which people use their phone to transport themselves into a different world, then fight each other (as monsters) and other monsters

Tags: story-identification, anime

I watched this a long time ago. In it, the characters use their phone to transport a copy of themselves into a different universe. In that universe, they go into a game place and fight other people as monsters that they've collected.

If I remember correctly, they can only turn into those monsters if they have a picture of them? So the characters take the risk to capture photos of these monsters.

Once they're ready to return, they can use their phones to return to the main world, and then sync their memories.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve this question by reviewing the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if it triggers any other memories.

Comment: Probably Chaotic, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo

Comment: Sounds very likely; https://youtu.be/om44XBfLcu8?t=486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this is very likely to be *[Chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series))* as per [Cartoon about a group of teenagers whose souls travel to multiple worlds with monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo).

> Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.
>
> There are two parts to the Chaotic world, Chaotic itself and Perim. Chaotic is where the people play an advanced version of the card/online game where they transform into the creatures. The games can be watched via monitor by other players.
>
> The second part is Perim. In Perim the creatures, locations and items from the game are real. Players from the Chaotic game can teleport into Perim and scan the locations, creatures and items with their scanners, gaining the ability to use them in their game. There are four tribes in Perim. Two tribes, the Overworld and the Underworld, have been at war over a great power called the Cothica. Despite their names, there is no definite Good and evil tribe, as both have different stories and interpretations of how the war began, with each tribe seeing the other as being evil. The Danians and Mipedians have since joined the war, turning it into a four-way conflict over the Cothica. It is said that the Mipedians were once united with the Overworlders and the Danians united with the Underworlders. It is still unknown why they separated

....

> When the players are in Chaotic/Perim they exist simultaneously on Earth. When a Chaotic player leaves Chaotic they become one person again and the Earth version of the player gains the memories of anything they experienced in the Chaotic/Perim world. This is awkward the first time they transport, as their online deck is blocked so that their Chaotic self can use it and their scanner becomes non functional, causing many people to believe they have broken their scanners until they are re-united with their Chaotic self.