# Early 2000s cartoon where these teens could transform into creatures with their phones

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

This cartoon could have been an anime but the point is it was a group of kids that could transform into creatures with their phones. The main character could transform into this lava creature thing.

In one episode the main character was looking for his father, when his arch enemies found him in his dads, some violence happens and his on the edge of a cliff with his dads phone on one side and his on the other so he takes his dads and leaves his with the villians.

It aired in Cartoon Network around 2010 to 2014.

Answer (score 2):

I think it was *Chaotic*. It didn't air on cartoon network, but on Fox Kids/Jetix. They had a bunch of "Scanners" that resembled later smartphones.

Comment: Whilst the intro is helpful it would be a lot better if you edited this to explain how it matches the given description.

Comment: I'll check it out immediately... Thanks

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo

Answer (score 1):

I found it. It's not *Chaotic*, but the idea is similar.

It was *[Redakai: Conquer the Kairu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu)*.

[image: DVD cover from Cartoon Network]

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?