# TV show featuring high school kids and monster

Tags: story-identification, tv

The show I'm looking for is highly unknown to the vast public. Despite all my attempts to find it (and I have for a long time), I have yet to find any clue that could lead me to it. The only memories I have of it are very vague, all I know it that it had a very unusual style of animation.

If memory serves me, it took place in a high school type setting. Everything about the show was animated (so no real life actors, etc.) Another thing I seem to remember is that the protagonists used some sort of digital tablets, and they would, using them, transfer into other worlds/galaxies to fight/capture monsters.

I used to watch this show somewhere back in the year 2006-2009 (I don't even remeber exactly). Also, it was broadcasted on French television (where I watched it). I could be an american show for all I know. Most likely this show was a huge flop and cancelled, hence why I have to this day failed to find anything relating to it.

Comment: This is way way way _way_ too broad. There are **dozens** of "capture the monsters" shows involving high school students. If you don't [edit] in some specific details, this will have too many possible answers to be a fit for this site.

Comment: Which is the problem! That's all I can remember unfortunately! At this point I'll just be happy with whatever possible answers I can receive lol. But thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is *[Chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series))* as per [Cartoon about a group of teenagers whose souls travel to multiple worlds with monsters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo).

> Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.
>
> There are two parts to the Chaotic world, Chaotic itself and Perim. Chaotic is where the people play an advanced version of the card/online game where they transform into the creatures. The games can be watched via monitor by other players.
>
> The second part is Perim. In Perim the creatures, locations and items from the game are real. Players from the Chaotic game can teleport into Perim and scan the locations, creatures and items with their scanners, gaining the ability to use them in their game. There are four tribes in Perim. Two tribes, the Overworld and the Underworld, have been at war over a great power called the Cothica. Despite their names, there is no definite Good and evil tribe, as both have different stories and interpretations of how the war began, with each tribe seeing the other as being evil. The Danians and Mipedians have since joined the war, turning it into a four-way conflict over the Cothica. It is said that the Mipedians were once united with the Overworlders and the Danians united with the Underworlders. It is still unknown why they separated

....

> When the players are in Chaotic/Perim they exist simultaneously on Earth. When a Chaotic player leaves Chaotic they become one person again and the Earth version of the player gains the memories of anything they experienced in the Chaotic/Perim world. This is awkward the first time they transport, as their online deck is blocked so that their Chaotic self can use it and their scanner becomes non functional, causing many people to believe they have broken their scanners until they are re-united with their Chaotic self.

It has the high school scenario. It has the digital game scanners. It has another world where people transform into (admittedly, not the same as capturing) monsters. :) And it comes up pretty often on this site.

### Trailer

Comment: Oh. my. freaking. god. THANK YOU! Wow, I'm literally speechless. That's the show I was looking for. LIKE DAMMMMNMNNN! Thank you so so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

This brings to mind [Code Lyoko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko).

It was a French animation with a mix of both drawn and CGI animation.

The protagonists would travel from the real world to a virtual world and fight monsters (not capture them).

No tablets in the real world, but plenty of computer screens to transfer real people to the virtual world.

[image: Computer screens]

Also, there were floaty screens in the virtual world.

It was only one virtual world, but with several sectors.

It ran originally from 2003 to 2007, so including repeats, could fit in the timeframe.

The characters all had quite pointy features, that might count as "unusual".

[image: Main Characters]

Comment: The show I was looking for has just been answered by someone else just now. But thank you anyways. Cheers.