# Show about some teenagers who take picture of some beings and turn into them so later can fight with others in a tournament?

Tags: story-identification, tv

There is this show that I watched when I was little and I want to watch it again because I want to see how the show is or you know....nostalgic moments.

I can remember one episode but not the name of it. It goes that the main characters go to this other where his creature or player character is sick or something hit him and he was hallucinating. He actually like took analysis and got the form of that player creature that got hit by something then he goes back to his world and then the main character transform into the player creature thingy I don't know remember and when he ready to fight his opponent he gets the same sickness as the that guy.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! When did you watch this? Was it live-action or animated? What language was it in? If you can remember those details, they'll greatly help us narrow it down.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are thinking of [*Chaotic*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series)).

> Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.
>
> There are two parts to the Chaotic world, Chaotic itself and Perim. Chaotic is where the people play an advanced version of the card/online game where they transform into the creatures. The games can be watched via monitor by other players.
>
> The second part is Perim. In Perim the creatures, locations and items from the game are real. Players from the Chaotic game can teleport into Perim and scan the locations, creatures and items with their scanners, gaining the ability to use them in their game. There are four tribes in Perim. Two tribes, the Overworld and the Underworld, have been at war over a great power called the Cothica. Despite their names, there is no definite good and evil tribe, as both have different stories and interpretations of how the war began, with each tribe seeing the other as being evil. The Danians and Mipedians have since joined the war, turning it into a four-way conflict over the Cothica. It is said that the Mipedians were once united with the Overworlders and the Danians united with the Underworlders. It is still unknown why they separated.

### Intro

You may be looking for [Episode 19, "A Fearsome Fate"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chaotic_episodes#Season_1_(2006%E2%80%9308)):

> Tom finally has a new scan of Maxxor, but when he transforms into the awesome OverWorld leader during a Drome match, he makes a startling discovery – the once-brave warrior is now a quivering coward. Seeking to unravel the mystery of Maxxor's illness, Tom must 'port to Lake Ken-i-po to consult with Najarin – if he can survive the Mugic trap inside the old wizard's castle.

Comment: If so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo