# Tryin to find this cartoon show in cafeteria where school students battle in flat screen with monsters or other students

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, disney

I think it was on a Nickelodeon variant channel or Disney (/maybe XD).

Here's a BIG CLUE I remember, they made toys for the show that uses Barcodes to collect monsters to battle with each other!

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. This is a bit terse at the moment, are there any other details you remember that you could [edit] in?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are looking for *[Chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_(TV_series))*

[image: Title image for Chaotic]

> Chaotic tells the tale of a teenage boy named Tom and his friend Kaz. They both play the Chaotic Trading Card/Online Game. Kaz always tries to tell Tom about a secret code to play for real which Tom refuses to believe. While playing online Tom receives the special password. When he enters the password into his game scanner he is transported to a place called Chaotic that is able to take him to another world where the characters, locations and items in the card game came to life.
>
> There are two parts to the Chaotic world, Chaotic itself and Perim. Chaotic is where the people play an advanced version of the card/online game where they transform into the creatures. The games can be watched via monitor by other players.

For [the collectible card game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaotic_Trading_Card_Game), you could scan in codes to add cards to your deck.

### Intro

It initially aired on 4Kids, but later on Jetix (part of Toon Disney), which merged into Disney XD, and Cartoon Network. You can currently watch episodes on Peacock, Tubi, or [their official YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCPdGCLOuKv_74yFawt2oehw).

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/144412/cartoon-about-a-group-of-teenagers-whose-souls-travel-to-multiple-worlds-with-mo?noredirect=1&lq=1