# I'm looking for a show where a teen (I think) can see or transform into this yellow monster

Tags: story-identification, animation

I'm looking for a show where a teen (I think) can see or transform into this yellow monster.

I remember the show being on Netflix at one point and it has this character travelling through these dungeon like places.

It was also 3D animated. There could have also been 2nd character besides the yellow monster he travels with, like a friend from high school.
I remember an episode where they where in a jungle temple and another one where they where in a dark maze.

Comment: Was the yellow monster humanoid? On four legs? Looked like a lion? A turtle? A slime? A robot?

Comment: Does *[Chaotic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267482/tryin-to-find-this-cartoon-show-in-cafeteria-where-school-students-battle-in-fla/267489#267489)* look familiar?

Comment: Does he use a device to transform? Cards? Magic jewel?

Comment: He was furry with red spots and I can't remember what he transformed with

Comment: Did the monster walk on two or four legs?

Comment: 2 and had hands that we would use to walk too sort of like a gorilla but this could be something that I misremebered

Comment: In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: 2016-2018 mmmmmmm

Comment: It's not [Adventure Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_Time), is it? It's 2D, mostly, but the rest mostly fits your description. It's also awesome. It's also also quite well-known :)

Comment: Nah but it does sorta fit the description

Comment: I also remember an episode where they cross this place full of chasms with these platforms with bridges connecting them.